# Why use a controller and a presenter together?

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvp

Sorry for mistakes but I'm not a native English speaker.

In the clean architecture there is a controller and a presenter, what is the sense?

Is it the same controller as in the MVC pattern?
Is it the same presenter as in the MVP pattern?

Why use both together?

Look at this: [image]

Can you give me an example?

Is the clean architecture similar to ports and adapters? If yes, where are the adapters?

Comment: What is the "clean architecture"? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Search on google clean architecture uncle bob

Comment: No no, it's another question @RC.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no value in mixing the MVP and MVC patterns. Although semantically similar, mixing presenters and controllers just results in confusion.

Could it be that this framework is using the terms independently of the known MVP/MVC patterns and gives them a different meaning within the context of the framework?